# How to upload image, word docs and/or PDF files via Paperclip rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I would like to enable users to upload **Word Docs** and **PDF** files to my rails application. My app is similar to a Pinterest app, users can create **Pins** where they attach a picture followed by a description (used **Paperclip** to attach the image to the **Pin**).

Here is my **Pins** model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
    validates :image, presence: true

    end
```

My **Pins** controller:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

 def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private

    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id] )
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this Pin" if @pin.nil?
    end


    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

I wonder if I just need to create another `has_attached_file` method for the **Word docs** and **PDFs** files within my **Pin** model and then create a view for users to upload the file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends...

If you want to attach an image **AND** a document you need to create another paperclip attribute for the document. On your model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }

has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

If you want to attach an image **OR** a document you can do the following:

```
has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

If you choose the first option you will need two file inputs on your view, with the second only one. It's not right or wrong on this. It depends what you want to do.

Comment: I'm using the first option (upload pdf/docs and image). I created an new input for the `:document` as followed: `<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :document %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :document, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>`. I tried it and it gives me an Error `undefined method document_content_type'`. Something is going on with my **Pins** controller : `def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end`.

Comment: did you run `rails generate paperclip pin document` to create the migration? This generator will create document_file_name, document_file_size, document_content_type and document_updated_at attributes on your Pin model

Comment: Just remembered to do that : Ran `  rails generate migration add_file_to_pin ` then `rake db:migrate`. Works fine now. I have to think **MVC**!

Comment: Now, for other users to view and/or download the pdf/docs should I simply create a view similar to the one I have for my image `<%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) % >` or is it more complex than that? If so, I'll have to dig more into that and try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: The easier would be <%= link_to "My document", @pin.document.url, target: "_blank" %> and let your browser to handle the pdf render. But I don't know if this will work with all browsers and .doc files. It works for me with ubuntu, chrome and .pdf files. Another option would be to create a controller action to download the file. Something like /pin/:id/download and use http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file.

Comment: @Leantraxxx Thanks you made my day. its very tough to find how to validate for image OR document using paperclip..