# Show and download PDF Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, sqlite, paperclip

I am making a website where users can upload images and PDF files.

I am working with Ruby on Rails and paperclip. I have a site called "show" where the user can see his post with "Name, Description and the Picture". But now I want to make that everybody can upload images OR PDF files and that there is a download link for each file next to the picture. I am using the sqlite database.

And on the place where normally the picture is I want to have a PDF logo where they can click on to see the PDF file.

Can someone help me in this situation?

My model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment :image, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
end
```

How I show the picture at the moment:

```
<%= image_tag @pictures[0].image.url(), class: "img-responsive" if @pictures.length > 0 %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you asking only how to display either an image preview (if image) or a PDF logo (if PDF file)? Is that all you need to know?

Comment: Have you managed to create a model for the PDFs? How far did you go?

Comment: I want to know the following steps:
1. Having a Model which allows to upload PDF files with a description, name, ... to sqlite with reference to the user who uploaded it. Now my code allows only to upload images but not PDF files. 

2. When the PDF file is in the database -> Have a site where you can find  the PDF logo to click and then I want to see the PDF file in the website. Like in owncloud. [https://demo.owncloud.org/]
There you can upload a PDF -> there is the PDF logo -> you can click and see the PDF file directly in the website. 

Now it works only with pictures but not PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a special treatment for PDF. Something like:

```
<% if @picture.image_content_type=="application/pdf" %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag "pdflogo.png"), @picture.image.url() %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag @picture.image.url(), class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```

assuming that the image is held in variable `@picture` and `pdflogo.png` contains the pdf logo. (The use of `@pictures[0]` and `if @pictures.length > 0` directly in the code for showing one image is not very DRY; this should be separated from the code for showing one picture.)

Comment: Thank you very much, but what can I make that the PDF file comes into my sqlite database? Because now my Model allows only to upload images and not PDF files. I have following now with the pictures: picture_name; picture_description and reference to the user who uploaded this image. But it doesn't work with PDF files.

Comment: you do a file upload, much in the same way as with your images. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715918/how-to-upload-image-word-docs-and-or-pdf-files-via-paperclip-rails-4